# javascript implementation of promise.all not working?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm going through eloquent javascript and have to implement promise.all. Here is my solution.

```
function all(promises) {
  return new Promise(function(success, fail) {
    var results = [];
    var failed = false;
    promises.forEach(function(promise) { 
      promise.then(function(result) {
        results.push(result);
      }, function (error) {
        failed = true;
        fail(error);
      });
    });
    if (!failed)
      success(results);
  });
}
```

Here are the tests I'm running it through.

```
// Test code.
all([]).then(function(array) {
  console.log("This should be []:", array);
});
function soon(val) {
  return new Promise(function(success) {
    setTimeout(function() { success(val); },
               Math.random() * 500);
  });
}
all([soon(1), soon(2), soon(3)]).then(function(array) {
  console.log("This should be [1, 2, 3]:", array);
});
function fail() {
  return new Promise(function(success, fail) {
    fail(new Error("boom"));
  });
 }
all([soon(1), fail(), soon(3)]).then(function(array) {
  console.log("We should not get here");
}, function(error) {
  if (error.message != "boom")
    console.log("Unexpected failure:", error);
});
```

My code is clearly wrong becuase it's outputting

This should be []: []

This should be [1, 2, 3]: []

We should not get here

the first of which is the only correct one. 
The actual solution which is from my flawed view basically the same as what I wrote works and can be found here: 
http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#17.2

Why does my code not work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @AliTorabi Don't be a jerk. Sometimes it's important to re-invent the wheel to gain a better understanding of programming and the language you're working with.

Comment: @AliTorabi As a learning exercise I belive it's a good thing to reimplement common functionality in order to better understand them. My understanding is that this is OP's goal.

Comment: I am not jerk anymore. Working on the code and question

Comment: `forEach` is synchronous, the `if (!failed)` statement will run before the promises are resolved.

Comment: I solved the problem. I am not jerk anymore...

Comment: @elclanrs but wouldn't the fact that forEach is synchronous mean that the code won't move on until the loop is finished? Thus if (!failed) won't be reached until the forEach loop is finished? Is the reason that these questions are wrong because promise.then will be asynchronous and will be executed after the code has moved on (but if this is true isn't forEach asynchronous since its content is not fully executed before control moves on?)?

Comment: The content of the `forEach` is fully executed. The `then`s get executed and they get put in the event loop's queue until they are ready to call the callback; the `forEach` is already done before the callbacks run.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is synchronous, the `if (!failed)` statement will run before the promises are resolved. You can do the following:

```
function all(promises) {
  var results = [],
      left = promises.length;
  if (!left) {
    return Promise.resolve(results)
  }
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    promises.forEach((p, i) => {
      Promise.resolve(p).then(x => {
        results[i] = x
        left -= 1
        if (left === 0) {
          res(results)
        }
      }, rej)
    })
  })
}
```

Using a sparse array you can keep the order, for example:

```
function timeout(n) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(n)
    }, n)
  })
}

var pa = timeout(200)
var pb = timeout(300)
var pc = timeout(100)

// success
all([pa, pb, pc]).then(console.log).catch(console.log) //=> [200, 300, 100]


// error
var pd = Promise.reject('error')

all([pa, pb, pc, pd]).then(console.log).catch(console.log) //=> error
```

Comment: This only seems to work when the last promise fulfills last. Also it doesn't work on empty inputs. And I'd recommend `.then(…, rej)` without a `catch` for simplicity

Comment: See my edit, hopefully that covers all cases this time.

Comment: Technically one could alter `promise.length` after having passed the array, and it would lead to no / too early resolution. But that's an obscure edge case, have an upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

You were reaching

```
 if (!failed)                 
   success(results);
```

so fast. if all promises done and it's the last one, all is resolved.

```
function all(promises) {
    return new Promise(function(success, fail) {
        var results = [];
        var failed = false;
        promises.forEach(function(promise) {
            promise.then(function(result) {

                results.push(result);

                if (results.length == promises.length) {
                    if (!failed)
                        success(results);
                }
            }, function (error) {

                failed = true;
                fail(error);
            });
        });


    });
}
```

testing your function:

```
all([soon(1), fail(), soon(3)]).then(function(array) {
    console.log("We should not get here");
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Fail");
    if (error.message != "boom")
        console.log("Unexpected failure:", error);
});
```

However, it still has the lack of result ordering.

Comment: Apart from lacking the order, it also does not work on empty inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your `.forEach` completes immediately, even before your promises have resolved. For each promise in your `.forEach`, it takes a random amount of time for the async computation to complete. For this [exercise](http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_http.html#h_MlI+KUOVBK), the time is `Math.random() * 5000`.

So, in each iteration an eventual result is "promised", and the `.forEach` continues. That's why you get an empty array: `[]`. The `.forEach` has completed before any of your promises resolve.

What you want to do is keep track of every promise that resolves, and as soon as you have the three resolved promises, you can call your `success` handler on the `results` array. You can do this by keeping a closure variable outside of the handlers passed into the `.then()` of each promise. And when each promise completes, you can increment that variable. In my solution I named this variable `count`:

```
function all(promises) {
  return new Promise(function(success, fail) {
    if (promises.length === 0) {
      return success([]);
    }
    const results = [];
    let count = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
      promises[i].then(val => {
        results[i] = val;
        count++;

        if (count === promises.length) {
          return success(results);
        }
      }).catch(err => fail(err));
    }
  });
}
```